# xs:restriction to xs:group?

Tags: xml, xsd

For example, there are phrasing elements we often see. (The code below is an IMAGE, it doesn't work.)

```
<xs:group name="Phrase">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="b"/>
        <xs:element ref="i"/>
        <xs:element ref="span"/>
        <xs:element ref="sub"/>
        <xs:element ref="sup"/>
        <xs:element ref="u"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

However, we don't want to nest `<b>`. So we define `<b>` element as:

```
<xs:group name="b.group">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="i"/>
        <xs:element ref="span"/>
        <xs:element ref="sub"/>
        <xs:element ref="sup"/>
        <xs:element ref="u"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

Yes, `<i>` element too.

```
<xs:group name="i.group">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="b"/>
        <xs:element ref="span"/>
        <xs:element ref="sub"/>
        <xs:element ref="sup"/>
        <xs:element ref="u"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

`<span>`, `<sub>` and `<sup>` elements might be able to Phrase group.

```
<xs:group name="span.group">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:group ref="Phrase"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

But again, we don't want to nest `<u>`.

```
<xs:group name="u.group">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="b"/>
        <xs:element ref="i"/>
        <xs:element ref="span"/>
        <xs:element ref="sub"/>
        <xs:element ref="sup"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

`<b>`, `<i>`, `<u>` definitions look redundant to us, and there is lower maintainability. How can we more meaningfully use Phase group on `<b>`, `<i>` and `<u>`?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to allow nested `b` elements, then restricting it to not have `b` children doesn't work - it can still have `b` grandchildren via an intermediate `i` or `u` element. There's no general way of solving this problem using simple recursive grammars such as DTD or XSD 1.0, except in a way that involves combinatorial complexity by having different type definitions for every level of nesting. The best way to do it is to add assertions using Schematron or XSD 1.1. Most content models in popular vocabularies make no attempt to restrict nesting of inline tags.